# How to use ImportXML in a Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Scenario:

I am trying to use Google spreadsheet to do something like this:

I've a set of Blog URL's (more than 50) for which I want to fetch title

Currently I am using the formula: **ImportXML(A2,"//h1[@class='entry-title']" )**

[image]

The Problem w/ this approach is that ImportXML calls are limited to 50 per spreadsheet and I've more than 50.

I browsed/searched - found out that we can use ImportXML calls in google apps script but did not found any example.

I found this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/XML_tutorial but I was hoping to use ImportXML function.

Can anyone describe or point to a resource where they have used ImportXML in a google apps script? Thanks!

Comment: url to tutorial is 404 as of today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a few spreadsheets, then pull the results together into a master spreadsheet, or are you doing >1000 or so. If you have lots, the XML_tutorial link you have is the place to start. 
But last time I checked, google-apps-script does not support google spreadsheet functions, if I remember, the feature request to support all spreadsheet functions in GAS was rejected.

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks for the information. I didn't knew that the functions were not supported in the GAS script. I'll try the workaround that you suggested aboyt pulling the results together in a master spreadsheet. Thanks for the reply, appreciate it.

Comment: How would the result of importxml be copied to a sheet given the script either runs to completion, or the code to copy the result is run before the XML import completes?

Comment: @jack I don't a script is needed, just use spreadsheet formulas. Did I miss something?

Comment: The cell containing importxml() copies the resulting XML to a cell in a different sheet (the sheet the user added the URL to). That cell changes. How would the importxml() cell know the cell to copy the result back to?